# Gherkin: Step definition with string which has double quoted element

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have step:

```
Then I should see validation error "Some text"
```

I use this string for XPATH in my step definition.
And I also have the text for this error like this:

```
"Some "text""
```

I tried to write something like this:

```
Then I should see validation error "Some \"text\""
```

But it wasn't helpful.
How should I manage this?

Comment: Maybe changing to using single quotes instead for wrapping the text will help -- Then I should see validation error 'Some "text"'.

Comment: don't work. The behavior is as for different step. But I need the unique step for both situation.

Comment: Try with escaping it twice...\\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gherkin file:**

```
@blog 
Feature: test for stackoverflow 

    Scenario Outline: Function to validate stackoverflow.
    
    Then I should see validation error "Some text"
```

**Java implementation (old version):**

```
@Then("I should see validation error \"(.*)\"")
public void sof(String someText) {
    System.out.println("Your text is: " + someText);
}
```

**Java implementation:**

```
@Then("I should see validation error {string}")
public void sof(String someText) {
    System.out.println("Your text is: " + someText);
}
```

**Console:**

```
Your text is: Some text
```

Comment: I know how to implement it. The question was about "Some "text"" in Gherkin file.

Comment: the 1st bloc is a Gerkin file sample

Comment: The problem is how to wrap quoted text into quoted text. I don't see this in your block.

Comment: I add console output in my response

Comment: sorry that didn't understand it ).  changing on  \"(.*)\" works for my. Thank you!